# Redirect index.php with parameters to index.php to others parameters using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, parameters, indexing

I have a shop which has migrated to another version, and the product catalog has changed.
Now, I have a table with the correspondence of the product ID and I need to create some redirection with htaccess like this:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?id_product=3&controller=product$ index.php id_product=101064&controller=product [R=301,L]
```

I know now the the old id `3` is now the id `101064`... but it doesn't work.

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^toto.php$ index.php?id_product=101064&controller=product [R=301,L]
```

and it works, but why doesn't the first code snippet work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `%{QUERY_STRING}`.

Put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_product=3&controller=product$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?id_product=101064&controller=product [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Oh thanks Justin for your answer !!! It works !
Must i create a couple of line for each id product i want to redirect ?

Comment: Sadly yes, but you have another solution (a little more complicated) with `RewriteMap`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/rewritemap.html#txt